# VirtualBox guest not recognizing increased HDD space

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, linux-mint

I've increased the size of my VDI using `VBoxManage modifyhd myHDD.vdi --resize 50000`but I can't make the guest recognize and use the new space.

## GParted on guest (Linux Mint)

[image]

## VirtualBox Manager on host (Windows 10)

[image]

Comment: Did you Oskar find out the reason? It seems I am experiencing same issue...

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using snapshot, you need to get rid of those if you enlarged the base VDI.

But be warned it is not supported to enlarge snapshots and can actually corrupt your disks, especially when doing it on the base disk.

Be sure to make a backup of your VM if you care for it.

Comment: Actually ii will if there is indeed a snapshot. Deleting a snapshot merge the base disk and the diff disk together which means you will be able to see the size increase.

Comment: snapshots were blocking my gparted or fdisk to see the expanded disk. VBOX 6.0.14

Comment: You were absolutely right for me: I was in a snapshot and new disk size could not be detected. I deleted the snapshot from VirtualBox (actually I losed nothing, it just merged snapshot to base memory change) then issueing `lsblk` showed the new free disk space. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like VirtualBox is seeing the increase in size (marked by the 48.83GB in your screenshot).  The reason why your guest OS doesn't is because it hasn't been partitioned.

You'll have to boot your Guest OS using a bootdisk that has parted or Gparted and repartition the disk to include the unallocated "sectors" of the space you just added.

[HowToGeek has an article](http://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/) that goes over how to do this in much greater detail.  The section "Enlarge the Virtual Machine's Partition" uses a Windows Guest but the steps to accomplish are done via a GParted boot disk.

Comment: I followed the HowToGeek article but I don't have any unallocated space available. I see the same thing as in the gparted image I have in the question. http://i.imgur.com/wItfGOB.png